# How to get user local machine hardware configuration using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, configuration, hardware

I want to gather user local machine hardware information for IT inventory for my organization. I want to develop single page ASP.NET website using C# where user may click and code will gather all information like processor details, hard disk drive details, RAM, and all motherboard details.

Comment: Many link available on internet to get these information. Please refer anyone. (https://codescratcher.com/windows-forms/get-computer-hardware-information-using-c/)  (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-2-Proce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Install System.Management using package manager and then code as below.

```
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
string id = string.Empty;
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
   {
    id = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
    break;
   }
```

We have many link to find hardware details, as below.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-3-Hardw

https://codescratcher.com/windows-forms/get-computer-hardware-information-using-c/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-2-Proce

Comment: is it gives client side hardware configuration? because I think the above links are showing only deployed computers detail. Am I right? I want asp.net code to get client information.

Comment: you mean whoever access your web application

Comment: Yes. anyone from my organization who will access my application, application will capture users' system information.